# Insert intermediate elements into array

Tags: perl

What is the best way in which to insert an element between each existing element of an array. The best I have so far is as follows:

```
my @array = ( 1 , 'foo', { }, [ ] );
my @new_array;
push @new_array, $_, ', ' for @array;
pop @new_array;
```

In reality, `@array` contains a mixture of HTML::Element objects and strings that are passed to HTML::Element's `splice_content` method with the aim of comma separating part of an elements contents.

Comment: That's not a bad way.  I was thinking [`List::MoreUtils::zip`](https://metacpan.org/pod/List::MoreUtils#zip-ARRAY1-ARRAY2-ARRAY3) would help, but you still have to create the array of `(', ') x $#array` to be the alternate items, so it doesn't look like a big saving over this.

Comment: Thank you for the zip suggestion, checking for a solution via the `List::*` modules hadn't crossed my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
my @array = ( 1 , 'foo', { }, [ ] );
(undef, my @new_array) = map {; ', ' => $_ } @array;
```

This takes advantage of the little known fact that you can use `undef` on the left-hand side of a list assignment to indicate that you don't care about that element.  (The semicolon in `map {;` is to make the parser understand that's a block and not a hashref.)

Comment: Very nice alternative. I was puzzling over the resultant syntax error before your semicolon fix.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would use a `map` instead of a `for` loop but keep your `pop`

```
my @new_array = map { $_, ', ' } @array;
pop @new_array;
```

Comment: In the back of my mind, I wanted rid of that lonesome pop, but this solution certainly keeps the intentions clear.